# How can I speed up my stock screener code?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, stock, yfinance

I have this python code that works, but is extremely slow. It takes about 10 secs per ticker to process its information. Thus, if you have 2000 tickers it can take hours to finish processing.

I was wondering if this could be edited in a way to speed up the process?

Thank you for your help. I am a beginner thus maybe doing certain things wrong.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
from datetime import datetime
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()

tickers = ['EDF.PA', 'anto.l', 'meta', 'iag.l', 'PFE','PKG','0700.hk', 'mbg.de']


df = pd.DataFrame({'Company': [''], 'P/S': [''],'P/E': [''],'P/B': [''],'Profit Margin(%)': [''],'ROE(%)': [''],'Current Ratio': [''],})
row = 0
for ticker in tickers: 
    ticker = yf.Ticker(ticker)
 
    quarterly_financials = ticker.quarterly_financials
    quarterly_financials['TTM'] = quarterly_financials.sum(axis=1)

    quarterly_balance_sheet = ticker.quarterly_balance_sheet
    quarterly_balance_sheet = quarterly_balance_sheet.iloc[:, [3, 2, 1, 0]]
    quarterly_balance_sheet.fillna('none', inplace=True)
    
    TTM = quarterly_balance_sheet.mean(axis=1)
    TTM.fillna('none', inplace=True)

    try:
        balance_sheet = ticker.balance_sheet
        balance_sheet = balance_sheet.iloc[:, [3, 2, 1, 0]]
    except Exception:
        pass


    #...Data...
    try:
        # Changes value of 'currency from 'GBp' to 'GBP'
        if ticker.info['currency'] == 'GBp':
            ticker.info['currency'] = 'GBP'
        # Makes sure market cap currency matches business currency
        if ticker.info['currency'] == ticker.info['financialCurrency']:
            MarketCap = ticker.info['marketCap']
        elif ticker.info['currency'] != ticker.info['financialCurrency']:
            MarketCap = ticker.info['marketCap']
            x = ticker.info['currency']
            y = ticker.info['financialCurrency']
            # Converts the market cap from, x (market cap currency), to y (financial currency), using the last available rate
            MarketCap = c.convert(MarketCap, x, y)
    except:
        MarketCap = 0
    
    try:
        TotalRevenue = (quarterly_financials.loc['Total Revenue'].iloc[-1])
    except:
        TotalRevenue = 0

    try:
        NetIncome = (quarterly_financials.loc['Net Income'].iloc[-1])
    except:
        NetIncome = 0

    try:
        TotalCurrentAssets = (quarterly_balance_sheet.loc['Total Current Assets'].iloc[-1])
        TotalCurrentLiabilities = (quarterly_balance_sheet.loc['Total Current Liabilities'].iloc[-1])
        TotalCurrentAssets/TotalCurrentLiabilities
    except:
        try:
            TotalCurrentAssets = (TTM.loc['Total Current Assets'])
            TotalCurrentLiabilities = (TTM.loc['Total Current Liabilities'])
            TotalCurrentAssets/TotalCurrentLiabilities   
        except:
            try:
                TotalCurrentAssets = (balance_sheet.loc['Total Current Assets'].iloc[-1])
                TotalCurrentLiabilities = (balance_sheet.loc['Total Current Liabilities'].iloc[-1])
                TotalCurrentAssets/TotalCurrentLiabilities
            except:
                TotalCurrentAssets = 0
                TotalCurrentLiabilities = 0
                print("Current Assets and Liabilities 4")

    try: 
        TotalAssets = (quarterly_balance_sheet.loc['Total Assets'].iloc[-1])
        TotalLiabilities = (quarterly_balance_sheet.loc['Total Liab'].iloc[-1])
        TotalAssets - TotalLiabilities
    except:
        try:
            TotalAssets = (TTM.loc['Total Assets'].iloc[-1])
            TotalLiabilities = (TTM.loc['Total Liab'].iloc[-1])
            TotalAssets - TotalLiabilities
        except:
            try:
                TotalAssets = (balance_sheet.loc['Total Assets'].iloc[-1])
                TotalLiabilities = (balance_sheet.loc['Total Liab'].iloc[-1])
                TotalAssets - TotalLiabilities
            except:
                TotalAssets = 0
                TotalLiabilities = 0 



    #...Creates Stock Screen df...
    try:
        df.at[row, 'Company'] = ticker.info['longName']
    except:
        df.at[row, 'Company'] = ''

    try:
        df.at[row, 'P/S'] = round((MarketCap/TotalRevenue), 2)
    except:
        df.at[row, 'P/S'] = 0

    try:
        df.at[row, 'P/E'] = round((MarketCap / NetIncome), 2)
    except:
        df.at[row, 'P/E'] = 0

    try:
        df.at[row, 'P/B'] = round((MarketCap / (TotalAssets - TotalLiabilities)), 2)
    except:
        df.at[row, 'P/B'] = 0

    try:
        df.at[row, 'Profit Margin(%)'] = round((NetIncome / TotalRevenue)*100, 2)
    except:
        df.at[row, 'Profit Margin(%)'] = 0

    try:
        df.at[row, 'ROE(%)'] = round((NetIncome / (TotalAssets - TotalLiabilities))*100, 2)
    except:
        df.at[row, 'ROE(%)'] = 0

    try:
        df.at[row, 'Current Ratio'] = TotalCurrentAssets/TotalCurrentLiabilities
    except:
        df.at[row, 'Current Ratio'] = 0
    
    row = row+1

display(df)
```

Comment: One obvious suggestion, parallelize…

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?